# Why is $\mathbb R^\times$ isomorphic to $\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ under addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870675/let-r-be-a-commutative-unital-ring-is-it-true-that-the-group-of-units-of-r), it is asked whether the additive group of a ring can be isomorphic to its group of units. The answer is yes: the trivial ring is the easiest example. However, the top-voted answer asserts that $\mathbb R\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (under addition) is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^\times$. Why is this the case?

I can verify that the units of the ring $\mathbb R\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ are of the form $(x,1)$, where $x\neq0$, so that there is an isomorphism between $(\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^\times$ and $\mathbb R^\times$ which takes $(x,1)$ to $x$, but I cannot find an isomorphism $\mathbb R^\times\to\mathbb R\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: "There is an isomorphism between $\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb R^\times$ which takes $(x,1)$ to $x$." This is a false statement. You just described an isomorphism between $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z_2)^\times$ and $\Bbb R^\times$, not an isomorphism between $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z_2,+)$ and $(\Bbb R^\times,\cdot)$. An isomorphism is in particular a function, not a "partial" function, so you described a function which does not have all of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z_2$ as its domain.

Comment: @runway44: Thanks, there was a typo in my post. I meant an isomorphism between $(\mathbb R\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^\times$ and $\mathbb R^\times$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{R}^\times$ is given by $(x,s)\mapsto(-1)^s e^x$.

The "parity bits" of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ corresponds to two connnected components of $\mathbb{R}^\times$ (the positive or negative numbers), and exponentials famously turn addition into multiplication, i.e. $e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$.

The inverse isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^\times\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is then $r\mapsto(\ln|r|,\,\mathrm{sgn}\,r)$.

Comment: It was a duplicate (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3Aisomorphic%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5CBbb%20R%5Ctimes%5CBbb%20Z_2%24&p=1)).