# Algebraic structure with 3 binary operators over an infinite set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an algebraic structure over an infinite set $S$, composed by $3$ different binary operators $*$, $+$,$×$ such that :

1. $*$ form an abelian group over $S$ and let's call $e$ its identity element
2. $*$ and $+$ form a field over $S$
3. $+$ and $×$ form a field over $S\setminus\{e\}$

If this structure exist what is its name? Can you give an example? If it does not exist, why? What is "wrong" in this structure?

Comment: A field has two operations - what do you mean by '+' forms a field over S?

Comment: There seemed to be a problem with the formatting; I tried to correct it but can you confirm that I got it right?

Comment: For items 2 and 3, can you specify which of the two operations is the multiplication and which the addition of the field? The notation would suggest + is addition, but the fact that 3 excludes e suggests that * is addition and + is multiplication in (2). Please clarify.

Comment: @ArnaudD. : thanks, your formatting is OK

Comment: @GuyPaterson-Jones: probably before ArnaudD formatting it wasn't clear, but it is the couple of binary operation $*$ and $+$ that form the first field, while the second field is formed by the couple $+$ and $×$.

Comment: @6005 : to mantain an internal coherency between the three item, since item 1 state that $*$ form a group over S, in item 2 $*$ must assume the 'additive' role and $+$ the 'multiplicative' role. From this descent that $+$ form a group over $S\setminus\{e\}$, so in item 3 $+$ must assume the 'additive' role and $x$ the 'multiplicative' role. For sake of notation we can use the 0 symbol for the identity element of $+$ operation and 1 for the identity element of $×$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is a name for such things, since they are rare, but they do exist. You are simply looking for a pair of fields $(S, *, +)$ and $(S-\{e\}, +, \times)$ where the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of the first field equals the additive group of the second field. Such a pair of fields can be constructed using [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918834/does-there-exist-a-pair-of-infinite-fields-the-additive-group-of-one-isomorphic/1919407#1919407)